# Stubbing callback function on readFileSync or safeLoad

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing, sinon-chai

I am trying to stub the following :

```
let file = yaml.safeLoad(fsExtra.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'), err => {
  logger.warn(err);
});
```

in a way that it get an `err` and run the `logger.warn`

but the problem is that when I do stubbing on either `safeLoad` or  `readFileSync` with any of the following codes, it never reaches the `logger.warn(err)`;

`sinon.stub().throws()` or `sinon.stub().reject()` or

```
sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
    throw new Error();
})
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, for simple, I create a `fsExtra` object to simulate the real node module.

`index.ts`:

```js
export const logger = {
  warn(message) {
    console.warn(message);
  }
};

export const yaml = {
  safeLoad(file, callback) {}
};

export const fsExtra = {
  readFileSync(filepath, options) {}
};

export function main() {
  const filepath = './.tmp/sinon.js';
  let file = yaml.safeLoad(fsExtra.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'), err => {
    logger.warn(err);
  });
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main, fsExtra, yaml, logger } from '.';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('main', () => {
  it('should safeLoad error', done => {
    const mError = new Error('fake error');
    const warnSpy = sinon.spy(logger, 'warn');
    const readFileSyncStub = sinon.stub<any, string>(fsExtra, 'readFileSync').returns('file content');
    const safeLoadStub = sinon.stub(yaml, 'safeLoad').callsFake((content, callback) => {
      callback(mError);
      done();
    });
    main();
    expect(readFileSyncStub.calledWith('./.tmp/sinon.js', 'utf8')).to.be.true;
    expect(safeLoadStub.calledWith('file content', sinon.match.func));
    expect(warnSpy.calledWith(mError)).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  main
Error: fake error
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58357977/index.spec.ts:1:3887)
    at callFnAsync (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:415:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:357:7)
    at Runner.runTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:535:10)
    at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:653:12
    at next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:447:14)
    at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:457:7
    at next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:362:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:425:5)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    ✓ should safeLoad error (46ms)


  1 passing (55ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |       75 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |       60 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58357977